# Can I undo the upgrade to Lollipop and go back to Kitkat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, restore

I have updated my Samsung S4 to Lollipop. And I don't like it. I need go back to Kitkat. I thought if I do factory reset I will get back to Kitkat, but that doesn't work, I'm still with fresh Lollipop. How to get back Kitkat?

My actions:

1. power + volume up+home
2. wipe data/factory reset
3. Confirmation - Yes

After restart I got back to Lollipop

Comment: You need to flash a KitKat firmware image. A factory reset does not reset the system partition. IIRC you can find most firmware images on sammobile.com

Comment: For what a factory-reset does, please see our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info). GiantTree is right, it doesn't touch "system stuff" – especially it cannot "restore" a previous Android version, as that was *replaced* by your update.

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade to kitkat by flashing stock kitkat firmware using Odin (the samsung flash tool).

First, download [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1130025&d=1339699793). Then download framework corresponding to your region from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9500/)

Install samsung drivers.

Next run odin on your pc and connect your phone while its in download mode (First go into download mode and then connect it. You go into download mode by turning off phone and then pressing and holding `Power Key + Home + Volume Down` till it gets into download mode. That "Downloading... Do not turn off target !!").

Make sure Odin recognizes you phone, it should say something like "com..." in one of the boxes which would mean odin has detected your phone. If it doesnt, your drivers arent proper.

Next extract the firmware you downloaded earlier using winrar.
Then in Odin,

a) Click the PDA button and choose the file with .tar.md5 extension.

b) Click the phone button and choose the file with modem in its name (skip this step if file not found).

c) Click the CSC button and select the file with CSC in its name.

d) Click the PIT button and select the .pit file (skip this step if file not found).

Make sure that the "Auto Reboot" and "F.Reset Time" check boxes are selected in Odin. At the same time, uncheck/disable the "Re-Partition" option. Click it only if a .pit file is being used.

Then click "start" button and wait a while. It may take sometime. After process is done odin should show "success" and then you can restart phone (may take sometime at first boot. Wait atleast upto 20mins by watch). You will be back to stock android KitKat rom.

Hope this helps :)